# Return specific value with filter

Tags: javascript

Assuming you have an array of objects:

```
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
```

And you want only the values of the `a` property of each object:

`[1, 2, 3]`

What functional approach can you use? I tried using filter:

```
arr.filter(x => x.a);
```

But of course, filter returns the whole object. Is there any other method I can use to achieve the result above? I mean, I could use `forEach`, I guess, or a for loop, but is there a better way? `map` would work IF I wanted all of the property values, but I would actually like to filter some of them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `map` to transform the type of each element. There is no magic filter that does a map as well; if you want to both `filter` and `map`, then you need to `filter` *then* `map`. These things are built to chain on purpose:

```
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];

arr.filter(x => x.a > 1).map(x => x.a) // => [2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm new to this stuff, sorry if my expectations are wrong. What would be more correct, filter then map or map and then filter? : - p

Comment: That's up to your specific needs.

Comment: it's usually simpler to map() _then_ filter() so that you don't need custom property names in your filter function. ex: `arr.map(pluck, "a").filter(gt, 1)`

Comment: `arr.map(x => { if (x.a > 1) return x.a }).filter(x => x)` would give the same result. But I guess it sounds more _logical_ to filter and then map.

Comment: Again, it's up to your specific needs. In this case, it doesn't matter, because we're dealing with the most over-simplified example possible. In the real world, map/filter and filter/map are completely different and often can only work one way. For example, if I ask you to return the age of all male students, you can do `students.filter(s => s.sex === 'male').map(s => s.age)`, but you cannot do `students.map(s => s.age).filter(age => ...?)`, because the input to `filter` will be an integer. The `sex` property has already been stripped away.

Comment: You're right. It all makes sense now. Thank you both.

Comment: @meagar: for one-off stuff like console calculations, i sometimes use a extra filter on a native function to be lazy with one custom callback, ex: `students.map(s=> s.sex=="male" && s.age).filter(Number)` ; provided nobody has an age of `0`... yeah, I still have to filter(), but I only need to write one callback...

Comment: @dandavis That's extremely contrived and completely beside the point.

Comment: @meagar: all i'm saying is that `.filter(Boolean)` or `.filter(String)` can cleanup a single map() callback that truthfully filters as it transforms, eliminating the need for a custom filter callback. i use the pattern often, though arrow functions are finally outmoding the need ;) OP asked if one could filter+map in one go, and the answer is no, but `.filter(Boolean)` on a sparse-ish map() result is almost as handy.

Comment: @meagar Might want to mention in your post that this is ES2015 code, and maybe how it might look to those still using ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is the great thing to get the same result in different ways.

But the better way is to use a regular for loop (check [Why most JavaScript native functions are slower than their native implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037888/why-most-javascript-native-functions-are-slower-than-their-naive-implementations#answer-21039294))

So you can do something like this:

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
var newArray = [];
for(var i in arr) { // or you can use: for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 var newArrValue = arr[i].a;
 if(newArrValue<3) // or some other if conditions to filter the values
 newArray.push(newArrValue);
}
console.log(newArray);
// and you will get [1, 2] as a result with newArrValue<3 if condition
```