# Why is the for() function faster than ES6 map() and some() for finding duplicates?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to benchmark the function that I am using to find out if there is a duplicated attribute in an array of objects using `map()` and `some()` versus another function that does the same thing but using a `for()` inside another `for()`.

```
let array = [ { "value": 41}, { "value": 12}, { "value": 32} ];

let itens = array.map(x => x.value);

let haveDuplicate = itens.some((item, idx) => itens.indexOf(item) !== idx);
```

versus:

```
let array = [ { "value": 41}, { "value": 12}, { "value": 32} ];

let haveDuplicate = false;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let x = array[i];
    for (let j = (i + 1); j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j]) {
            let y = array[j];
            if (x.value === y.value) {
                haveDuplicate = true;
                return;
            } else {
                haveDuplicate = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using JsPerf I can see that the function that uses `map()` and `some()` runs 90% ~ 100% slower. 
[Click here to check the benchmark](https://jsperf.com/testing-performance-of-finding-duplicate-javascript-v2)

Can someone explain to me why?

EDIT: this question is duplicate of this one: [Why most JavaScript native functions are slower than their naive implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037888/why-most-javascript-native-functions-are-slower-than-their-naive-implementations)

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. The use of `.map()`, `.reduce()`, etc. are becoming chronically overused in our community. Imagine putting 500 `.map()` calls, each 80% slower, into an app..uhg.

Comment: Finding logic using the function `map` is crazy!

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `let a = x => x.value;

let itens = array.map(a);`

Comment: The Array methods call a function (the callback you pass to them) for each element in the array, whereas the loop doesn't call any.

Comment: **Loop iterations:** your logic, your logic, your logic, your logic, ... **Array methods iterations:** function call + your logic + internal logic, function call + your logic + internal logic, function call + your logic + internal logic, ...

Comment: `.map()` - Internally: **Pre-loop:** Create an Object, steps call 5 internal functions. **Each-Iternation:** steps call 5 internal functions and the external callback function. `for()` - internally: **Pre-loop**: 1 internal function call, **Each-Iteration:** 6-7 internal function calls.

Comment: keep in mind the internal function calls mentioned are in machine language code; while the `.map()` external callback is JavaScript code run in the VM (V8)

Comment: Your premise is a bit biased: try to initiate your array with 30000 objects and you'll see the some one is faster.

Comment: map() does more: outputs new arrays, filters empty slots ex: `Array(55).map(f)`, accepts an optional `this` context, etc.  `_.map` is a closer approximation to for loops, without all the spec-required baggage.

Comment: Gonna review all the comments for understanding, but I did a research and found 4 mainly used methods for this purpose, doing the benchmark here: https://jsperf.com/testing-performance-finding-duplicate-value-javascript

Comment: It really [should be equally fast](https://youtu.be/EhpmNyR2Za0?t=17m15s) (apart from having to create an extra array).

Comment: @TheReason How come it is a possible duplicate if I am not using forEach in this question? Unflag please.

Comment: it does similar things except returning the mapped value

Comment: My doubt is between map/some versus for(), also I am updating tonight the question to include more information.

Comment: @CassianoMontanari take a look at general overview about this problem [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037888/why-most-javascript-native-functions-are-slower-than-their-naive-implementations)

Comment: @TheReason gonna check those, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few reasons the loop version is faster.

1. The `.map` version can have overhead of calling functions, which requires allocate memory, push to stack, some runtime checking the function is callable, etc. It may get optimized, or not.
2. The code are not equivalent. `.indexOf` need to scan the whole array if item does not exist where as the for loop version the second loop does not always scan the whole array.

---

Also, you better to use `Set` (or just object incase `Set` is not available) to do the duplicate check.

Pick the right data structure/algorithm is usually the most important optimization step.

```
let itens = array.map(x => x.value);

haveDuplicate = new Set(itens).size !== itens.length
```

Comment: *"Pick the right data structure/algorithm is usually the most important optimization step."*  And it's not always an easy step. e.g, the Set way would be slower than any other with a big Array which has duplicate values at the beginning of the array.

Comment: @Kaiido you may have a very specific use case, which a specific solution will perform better for you. But here I just provide a general solution/suggestion that for the general use cases which I assumed is what OP wants.

Comment: Yes sure, just wanted to note that this is indeed an hard step, and that this *right algorithm choice* is not an easy thing and mainly depends on the data.

Comment: That's true. Especially the right algorithm to do may change over time. e.g. when deal with cryptography and security

Comment: The faster algorithm would be `function hasDuplicates(array) { const set = new Set; for (const {value} of array) { if (set.has(value)) return true; else set.add(value); } return false; }`

Comment: You should first emphasize this: **The codes are not equivalent.** The benchmark makes no sense in OP because algorithms are different. Once this fixed, OP can start comparing `.some` vs `for`.

Comment: @RaphaMex can you please edit an test case to make the algorithms equivalent?

Comment: @CassianoMontanari: I have no time for this, but it should not be hard to do. Write your `for` loop based on `some` [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill). Also, see Bergi's comment: you need no `map`.